# Jquery Mobile hide Header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page that hide the header if the window height is less than width thes is my code.

```
if ($(window).width()> $(window).height()){
$("#header").hide();
}
```

This is the output

[image]

As you can see the header is hide but the space where the header is not remove. My question is how to remove the space after I hide the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have `data-position="fixed"` in your header

so you need to add `margin-top` css to your content to what the header height is so that it moves up. you can do this dynamically. When you resize back you can reset the margin back to 0px

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/scrva2hz/

**Jquery**

var headheight = $("#header").height();

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
if ($(window).width()> $(window).height()){
$("#header").hide();
$(".ui-content").css("margin-top", "-"+headheight+"px");
}
else {
$("#header").show();
$(".ui-content").css("margin-top","0px");   
}
});
```

Comment: I try your code and i just replace `$(".ui-content")` to `$(".ui-panel-wrapper")` to work as i need! TY for you!